# Marker is added twice on api call in Async task

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-asynctask, google-maps-markers

I am implementing google map application where I am making an api call to my server and receiving the current location of few person or object or any thing you can consider it as. At each api call the response location of each object changes. On receiving the response I am adding marker on the basis of location and id received. I am able to add up the marker but I in the adding process of marker I am deleting all the previous marker added in the same process but unfortunately it is working but maintains two marker instance for same id.

This is the thread call for the api call

```
public class GetNearbyVehicle extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<ActiveVehiclePosition>> {
static GoogleMap mMap;

static ArrayList<ActiveVehiclePosition> activeVehiclePositionArrayList;
static HashMap<ActiveVehiclePosition, Marker> activeVehiclePositionHashMap;
public static HashMap<ActiveVehiclePosition, Marker> getNearbyVehicle(GoogleMap mMap1, HashMap<ActiveVehiclePosition, Marker> oldVehiclePositionHashMap){
    String url= "some url";
    mMap= mMap1;
    if(oldVehiclePositionHashMap != null){
        for (Map.Entry<ActiveVehiclePosition, Marker> entry : oldVehiclePositionHashMap.entrySet()) {
            Marker m= entry.getValue();
            m.remove();
        }
    }
    new GetNearbyVehicle().execute(url);
    return activeVehiclePositionHashMap;
}
@Override
protected ArrayList<ActiveVehiclePosition> doInBackground(String... params) {
    String url= params[0];
    try {
        ArrayList<ActiveVehiclePosition> ar= new ArrayList<>();
        ar= JsonConverter.getNearByVehicle(url);
        if(ar != null){
            activeVehiclePositionArrayList= ar;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return activeVehiclePositionArrayList;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ActiveVehiclePosition> activeVehiclePositions) {
    super.onPostExecute(activeVehiclePositions);

    activeVehiclePositionHashMap= new HashMap<>();
    if(activeVehiclePositions != null){
        for(int i=0; i<activeVehiclePositions.size(); i++){
            MarkerOptions markerOptions= new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(activeVehiclePositions.get(i).getLatLng());
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            markerOptions.title(activeVehiclePositions.get(i).getDriver().getName());
            activeVehiclePositionHashMap.put(activeVehiclePositions.get(i), mMap.addMarker(markerOptions));
        }
    }

}
```

}

This is the location from where I called the thread.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    currLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    if(sourceMarker != null && LOOKING_FOR == CURRENT_LOCATION_POINTER) sourceMarker.remove();
    else if(destinationMarker != null && LOOKING_FOR == FINAL_LOCATION_POINTER) destinationMarker.remove();
    if(LOOKING_FOR == CURRENT_LOCATION_POINTER){
        setCurrentLocationMarker(currLatLng, sourceMarker);
        activeVehiclePositionArrayList= GetNearbyVehicle.getNearbyVehicle(mMap, activeVehiclePositionArrayList);
    }
    else if(LOOKING_FOR == FINAL_LOCATION_POINTER){
        setCurrentLocationMarker(currLatLng, destinationMarker);
    }
}
```

[image]

The marker which I added from api call is in magenta color.
I could not understand what is wrong with it. Can anyone help me out?

NB: In real time what is happening out here is, out of two marker one disappears and takes new position and this continues one after another alternately.

But ideally what should happen is all should disappear simultaneously and take new position simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Although I managed to get the thing working by making the async task as inner class **but I still want to know if I keep Async Task as independent class then how will I do it?**

```
private static class GetNearbyVehicle extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<ActiveVehiclePosition>> {
    ArrayList<ActiveVehiclePosition> activeVehiclePositionArrayList;
    public static void getNearbyVehicle(){
        String url= "some url";
        if(oldVehiclePositionArrayList != null){
            for (Map.Entry<ActiveVehiclePosition, Marker> entry : oldVehiclePositionArrayList.entrySet()) {
                Marker m= entry.getValue();
                m.remove();
            }
        }
        new GetNearbyVehicle().execute(url);
    }
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ActiveVehiclePosition> doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url= params[0];
        try {
            ArrayList<ActiveVehiclePosition> ar= new ArrayList<>();
            activeVehiclePositionArrayList= JsonConverter.getNearByVehicle(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return activeVehiclePositionArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ActiveVehiclePosition> activeVehiclePositions) {
        super.onPostExecute(activeVehiclePositions);

        oldVehiclePositionArrayList= new HashMap<>();
        if(activeVehiclePositions != null){
            for(int i=0; i<activeVehiclePositions.size(); i++){
                MarkerOptions markerOptions= new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(activeVehiclePositions.get(i).getLatLng());
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
                markerOptions.title(activeVehiclePositions.get(i).getDriver().getName());
                oldVehiclePositionArrayList.put(activeVehiclePositions.get(i), mMap.addMarker(markerOptions));
            }
        }


    }
}
```